# Instructions for installing libdvdcss on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and trying to get VLC to work. I installed VLC, and libdvd-pkg from terminal. Then I downloaded libdvdcss, I need instructions on how to get it to terminal to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

**Installing libdvdcss**

> Legal warning: Check with your local laws to make sure usage of
>   libdvdcss2 would be legal in your area.

From Ubuntu 15.10 onwards, libdvd-pkg is available to ease the installation of libdvdcss.

Install the libdvd-pkg package (no need to add third party repositories) via Synaptic or command line:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

Then run the following commands to complete the libdvdcss installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

Comment: Already installed libdvd-pkg. It still seems to be scrambled

Comment: "Follow libdvd-pkg's instructions to let it download, compile, and install libdvdcss." Would be worth mentioning what instructions those are.

Comment: Try unscrambling with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - open terminal.

Step 2: - copy/paste into terminal:

> sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg

Step 3 - copy/paste into terminal:

> sudo /usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh

Step 4 - Hit Enter

Step 5 - Enter password

Step 6 - When installation is complete: close terminal.

Tested successfully on Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Comment: Worked with Xenial with unity desktop as well.